# How to get wifi working on Dell inspiron mini 1011 without wifi on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: wireless, dell

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.04 32-bit on my Dell inspiron mini 1011, and I can't use wired, nor does most other solutions people have said helped, so what do I do?

~Thanks in advanced,

Blade

Comment: buy a compatible Wi-Fi Dongle

Comment: Please [update](http://askubuntu.com/posts/675408/edit) your question with `lspci -nnk | grep Net -A2` output from a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + t)

Answer (score 0):

Well lets go over the obvious first

The mini series should have an ethernet port so that would be your best bet.

It should also have bluetooth so there should be some options there:
[From Android](https://www.androidpit.com/share-wifi-over-bluetooth) and [From Ubuntu](http://www.clearevo.com/ecodroidlink/ubuntu_bluetooth_internet_setup/).

If you are still having issues try copying the files to a usb or use a generic usb wifi dongle since they do not usually require non standard drivers.

Would you be able to give a short list of the things you have already tried and the reasons why they have not worked?